# Why does the center of $R$-$\mathbf{mod}$ consist of multiplication maps induced from central elements of $R$?

Tags: category-theory, modules

The center of a category $C$ is the class of natural transformations from $1_C$ to $1_C$. In $R-\textbf{mod}$, I have been able to show that the morphisms $\eta_M(c):x\mapsto cx$ for $x\in M$ and $M$ and $R$-module, and $c$ central in $R$, give a natural transformation from the identity functor to itself.

How can you show that all natural transformations actually have this form? If $\eta$ is in the center of $R$-mod, then for any modules $M$ and $N$, and any morphism $f:M\to N$,  $f\eta_M=\eta_Nf$. I've been trying to evaluate this maps at clever points in $M$, but nothing sticks out.

This mostly comes from Exercise 6 on page 26 of Jacobson's BAII.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose $\eta$ is a natural tranformation. Its value at the left $R$-module $R$ is a map $\eta_R:R\to R$ of left $R$-modules. You can easily check that $c=\eta_R(1)$, the image of $1\in R$, belongs to the center $Z(R)$ of $R$.

If now $M$ is any $R$-module, and $m\in M$, there is a unique map $f:R\to M$ such that $f(1)=m$. Using naturality of $\eta$, we see that $$\eta_M(m)=\eta_M(f(1))=f(\eta_R(1))=f(c)=cm.$$ We thus see that the map $\eta_M:M\to M$ is in fact just left multiplication by $c$.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: How can we show that $c\in Z(R)$?

Answer (score 2):

If $U : \mathsf{Mod}(R) \to \mathsf{Set}$ is the forgetful functor, then there is a natural inclusion map $\mathrm{End}(1_{\mathsf{Mod}(R)}) \hookrightarrow \mathrm{End}(U)$. But $U$ is represented by $R$, hence $\mathsf{End}(U) \cong \mathsf{End}(R) \cong Z(R)$ by Yoneda. The map $Z(R) \cong \mathrm{End}(U)$ is given by $c \mapsto (m \mapsto cm)$ (by the proof of Yoneda) and since $m \mapsto cm$ is a module endomorphism, we see $\mathrm{End}(U)=\mathrm{End}(1_{\mathsf{Mod}(R)})$.